# How do I convert a Peekable iterator back to the original iterator?

Tags: rust

I want to implement an algorithm that skips `!` or `!^num` at the start of a string:

```
fn extract_common_part(a: &str) -> Option<&str> {
    let mut it = a.chars();
    if it.next() != Some('!') {
        return None;
    }
    let mut jt = it.clone().peekable();

    if jt.peek() == Some(&'^') {
        it.next();
        jt.next();
        while jt.peek().map_or(false, |v| !v.is_whitespace()) {
            it.next();
            jt.next();
        }
        it.next();
    }
    Some(it.as_str())
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(extract_common_part("!^4324 1234"), Some("1234"));
    assert_eq!(extract_common_part("!1234"), Some("1234"));
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=80a30aaed5ee27b99bce12452932851c)

This works, but I can not find way to return from `Peekable` to `Chars`, so I have to advance `it` and `jt` iterators. This causes duplicate code.

How can I return from `Peekable` iterator to corresponding `Chars` iterator, or maybe there is a simpler way to implement this algorithm?

Answer (score 7):

In short, you cannot. The general answer is to use something like [`Iterator::by_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref) to avoid consuming the `Chars` iterator:

```
fn extract_common_part(a: &str) -> Option<&str> {
    let mut it = a.chars();
    if it.next() != Some('!') {
        return None;
    }

    {
        let mut jt = it.by_ref().peekable();

        if jt.peek() == Some(&'^') {
            jt.next();
            while jt.peek().map_or(false, |v| !v.is_whitespace()) {
                jt.next();
            }
        }
    }

    Some(it.as_str())
}
```

The problem is that when you call `peek` and it fails, the underlying iterator has *already been advanced*. Getting the rest of the string will lose the character that tested false, returning `234`.

However, Itertools has [`peeking_take_while`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.6.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.peeking_take_while) and [`take_while_ref`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.6.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.take_while_ref), both of which should solve the issue.

```
extern crate itertools;

use itertools::Itertools;

fn extract_common_part(a: &str) -> Option<&str> {
    let mut it = a.chars();
    if it.next() != Some('!') {
        return None;
    }

    if it.peeking_take_while(|&c| c == '^').next() == Some('^') {
        for _ in it.peeking_take_while(|v| !v.is_whitespace()) {}
        for _ in it.peeking_take_while(|v|  v.is_whitespace()) {}
    }

    Some(it.as_str())
}
```

---

Other options include:

- using a crate like [strcursor](https://crates.io/crates/strcursor) which is designed for this kind of incremental advance over a string.
- do the parsing on regular strings directly, and hope the optimizer eliminates redundant bounds checks.
- Use a regex or other parsing library

Comment: 5 seconds.  Didn't even get the "new answer" notification.  :P

Comment: @DK. well then, I'll just steal the parts of your answer that I didn't say. Note how I don't have to put the author disclaimer so it looks even more legit ;-)

Comment: **Disclaimer**: Shepmaster got the suggestion for `strcursor` from the author of `strcursor`, which is me.  It should be taken more as an example, not as a recommendation.

Comment: @DK. *boooooooo*

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in the result, without validation:

```
fn extract_common_part(a: &str) -> Option<&str> {
    a.chars().rev().position(|v| v.is_whitespace() || v == '!')
        .map(|pos| &a[a.len() - pos..])    
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(extract_common_part("!^4324 1234"), Some("1234"));
    assert_eq!(extract_common_part("!1234"), Some("1234"));
}
```